# how to make image still high quality when make it bigger?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to make an homepage like apple.com:
here is the image from apple:
[image]

and here is mine:

[image]

How can I make mine image fullfill like apple?

Comment: Many solutions available. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There's a good solution available with the srcset attribute. For more details look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)
It'll look like this:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Be sure to check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) in order to find out, if your implementation of choice also works in the browsers you are targeting.